# Passing JSON parameter via GET request to MVC controller

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, typescript

I'm trying to pass some JSON on the querystring of a GET request to an MVC controller, but can't seem to get it to come through as anything other than `null`.

**Ajax (through TypeScript)**

```
$.ajax(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  data: { 'request': JSON.stringify(this.request) },
  dataType: 'json'
})
```

**MVC Controller**

```
[Route("stuffAndThings/{request?}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetStuff(requestType request)
{
}
```

Because this is TypeScript, the object being passed is the TypeScript representation of the C# model, including several custom objects

**TS class**

```
class requestType {
  pageData: PageData;
}
```

**C# class**

```
public class requestType
{
  public PageData pageData { get; set; } = new PageData();
}
```

Looking at the request in devtools, it appears to be being passed correctly on the querystring, but always comes through on the controller as null.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

To address a couple of comments, the controller method is purely for data retrieval, and does have the potential in the future to be turned into a WebAPI method, so I would like to keep it as a GET request if possible.

Comment: probably you need to pass PageData directly without wrapping in requestType

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` means you are passing a `string`. Your parameter needs to be `string request` (and then deserialize it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I thought you could pass JSON objects directly to MVC controllers as specific types without having to pass them as strings? Admittedly, I may have incorrectly used JSON.stringify...

Comment: @HarutyunImirzyan This is a simplified example of my classes, the `requestType` class actually has several other properties that are also passed

Comment: " I thought you could pass JSON objects directly to MVC controllers as specific types "...you can, but since you stringified your JSON before you sent it, and then wrapped it in another object, it just appears to the server as a single string variable called "request". It doesn't look like JSON any more. If you want to talk using JSON though, you're much better off using a POST, especially as your method called "DoStuff" looks like it sends data and runs an action, rather than just passively requesting info, so semantically it's much  more of a POST than a GET style request anyway.

Comment: Try encoding UrlEncode. It may be happening that PageData contains chars which are not valid for query string. However, considering your reason for doing this is due to the length of the URI, using JSON will be self-defeating (introducing more characters than required). I suggest you send your parameters in body of a POST request,

Comment: @ADyson That's my bad code obfuscation, I'll change it shortly, but the controller method is purely for data retrieval, so I'd like to stick with a GET if at all possible. POST was my first choice, but a colleague talked me out of it, pointing out that in the future this may be changed to a WebAPI method

Comment: If it's got to be a GET, you're much better off sending normal querystring parameters. $.ajax will sort that for you automatically - I think you can just specify `data: { 'request': this.request }` or even `data: this.request`. MVC/Web API can accept either data type as long as you let it know. Sending JSON on the querystring just isn't really something that's done. If your `request` object is too large or complex for a querystring though you'll have to use POST or another method.

Comment: @ADyson I'll admit I have been flipping between the two. The reason for the JSON instead of querystring parameters is I need to pass a number of parameters representing a collection of custom objects. I think at this point I am leaning towards a POST

Comment: @DarkHippo I think that's wise if the object is complex and/or of potentially unpredictable size. You often find that things like complex searches use a POST if there are a lot of parameters to submit, simply because of the complexity of the request, even though they sound like they really ought to be a GET semantically.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC controller you will get the parameter as string because you have passed parameters as string through GET request

```
[Route("stuffAndThings/{request?}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetStuff(string request)
{

}
```

Make `requestType` class serializable,
now in your method you have to deserialize the json string into your object

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(request)))  
{   
   DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(requestType));  
   requestType requestObj = (requestType)deserializer.ReadObject(ms);   
    //your code here   
}
```